# How to retrive localized message in template play framework 2.4

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization

I have problem with internationalize strings in Play framework 2.4

When i use something like this

```
class NewArticleController @Inject()(menuProvider: MenuProvider, val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport  {
...
println(Messages("article.new"))
```

It works fine. I have got message in language defined in Accepted-Languages header.This is play.api.i18n.Messages

But when i do something like this in template

```
@play.i18n.Messages.get("article.new")
```

I always got english message. If i remove 'en' languages from supported, then i have got key for message.

How can i resolve apropirate message in template?

Comment: Your example written in java. Scala library placed under `play.api.` And you don't need full path, `play.api.i18n._` imported by default.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but you can specify another argument for get-method.

@play.i18n.Messages.get(lang, "article.new")

And you can pass lang as parameter to template.